# Forwarding an Email(with attachments) without downloading the actual attachments

Tags: smtp, imap, gmail-api, email-attachments, gmail-imap

I want to forward an Email which has some attachments.

- I don't want to download the attachments and then upload again the same attachments
- I want to achieve this functionality on IMAP servers like (Gmail, Yahoo, etc)
- For outlook account, I have achieved this using smart forward concept but that does not apply on IMAP
- I am developing an Android application

I tried URLAUTH IMAP extension with Gmail server but that does not work
- In response to GENURLAUTH request, server responded the unknown request

I checked with Gmail app and Microsoft Outlook Android app and they already provide this feature

Expected result - Emails are forwarded on Gmail/Yahoo servers without actually downloading the attachments on your mobile devices.

Please suggest how this functionality can be achieved on Gmail server

Answer (score 1):

Sorry.  It can't be done with baseline IMAP.  There are extensions for that (URLAUTH and other [Lemonade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemonade_Profile) friends) but they are rarely deployed.

The Gmail app does not use IMAP for Gmail accounts.  Use the Gmail HTTP [API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) for Gmail, which is somewhat richer than IMAP.

The Outlook APP also does not use IMAP for outlook accounts.  It uses either EAS or the various Microsoft HTTP Email APIs.